# How in C++ to map run-time type discriminators to template instances (without manually enumerating them all)?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

Given an `enum` of type discriminators representing various small types:

```
enum TypesEnum {
    IntT, 
    DoubleT, 
    ShortStringT
};
```

Suppose I have a `template SomeType<typename A, typename B, typename C>`. This is a type that I read and write to sets of memory-mapped files, whose layout/stride is determined by the types; the runtime types are stored as a triplet of the enum discriminators above.

I need to write various tools which can load these files and perform operations on them, like `SomeType<A,B,C> => SomeType<B,A,C>` and so forth.  In these tools, I therefore have a rather awkward layer which translates the type discriminators on-disk into generic lambdas wrapping operations implemented with template instances for the correct types.

This looks like:

```
static std::map< std::tuple<Discrim, Discrim, Discrim>, some_op_fn_t > = 
    {
        {std::make_tuple(IntT, DoubleT, ShortStringT), SomeOperation<int,double,char[16]>() },
         std::make_tuple(IntT, IntT, ShortStringT), SomeOperation<int,int,char[16]>() },
        ...
    };
... look up the correct function pointer and call it with the path to the files ...
```

where `typedef std::function<bool(void)> some_op_fn_t`, whose implementations in `template<A,B,C> class SomeOperation` do a bunch of work with side-effects to disk.

Now, this quickly gets pretty tedious as the list of types and number of different operations grow.  The trick is I *cannot* use virtual inheritance to simply have a type-erased `SomeType` which operates on abstract/virtual value types; it's much too slow to do the indirection and pointer chasing.  I need to have dead reckoning and contiguous, packed value data, suitable (in the case of floats and doubles) for passing directly to BLAS.

Are there any techniques for automating the creation of interfaces/layers such as this?  Something like a type-level combinations would help, where I could connect the enum to the types just once, and then expand all the instances of the mapping.  Is that possible?

Worst case I can write a script to generate the code, but ugh...

Comment: The easy part: You may have a traits to map `enum` `IntT` to `int`, `DoubleT` to `double` (and/or vice versa). The more complicated part is the Cartesian product of your enum.

Comment: Hmm I can see a trait mapping from `IntT` to `int`, but only at compile time?  Even if I had a vector of product enum tuples, I still couldn't just loop over it to add `map.insert({ i, SomeOperation<Trait<i.get<0>()>.type,Trait<i.get<1>()>.type,Trait<i.get<2>()>.type>() })` correct?

Comment: So, why do you think `std::function` is going to be much faster than a vtable lookup?  Is it that the `std::function` can operate on packed memory, while vtables (as far as you know) require heap/free store allocation?  A vtable is just a pointer to a table of functions with a peculiar layout in extreme cases.  Second, *what* about your solution gets tedious?  "this gets tedious" is like "this doesn't work"; is the problem that you are typing those structures out by hand?

Comment: `std::function` is just to wrap the initial call, the point is that `SomeOperation` internally needs to know its types. I don't care about indirection initially, I just can't have any on the inside of `SomeOperation` or `SomeType`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that as I add operations to the system and types to the enum, maintaining these tables becomes a hassle.

Comment: So, write code that does takes a `template<Enum...>class Z` and a range of `Enum start, Enum end` and a count, and does the compile-time cross product of your enum entries and a map type, and populates a map with `make_tuple(a,b,c,d) -> Z<a,b,c,d>{}()`?  But really, a `map` is the wrong solution: a flat array of some kind with a smart `operator[]`.  This, naturally, will generate `O(n^k)` both code and data, where `n` is the number of enum entries and `k` is the arity of the tuples, so should be done with caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an easy part, a mapping between type and enum value:

```
template <typename T> struct EnumValue;

template <> struct EnumValue<int> : std::integral_constant<TypesEnum, IntT> {};
template <> struct EnumValue<double> : std::integral_constant<TypesEnum, DoubleT> {};
template <> struct EnumValue<char[16]> : std::integral_constant<TypesEnum, ShortStringT> {};
```

Then an easy helper function:

```
using TupleT = std::tuple<int, double, char[16]>;

template <typename ... Ts> // Might be T1, T2, T3, but lazy to type
constexpr auto make_my_pair()
{
    return std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(EnumValue<Ts>::value...), &SomeOperation<Ts...>);
}
```

Now the Cartesian product using `index_sequence`

```
template <std::size_t I>
constexpr std::pair<TypesEnumTuple, some_op_fn_t>
make_my_pair()
{
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<TupleT>();
    return make_my_pair<
        std::tuple_element_t<(I / (N * N)) % N, TupleT>,
        std::tuple_element_t<(I / N) % N, TupleT>,
        std::tuple_element_t<(I / 1) % N, TupleT>
    >();
}

template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::map<TypesEnumTuple, some_op_fn_t>
make_my_map(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {make_my_pair<Is>()...};
}
```

And finally:

```
// 27 = std::tuple_size<TupleT>() * std::tuple_size<TupleT>() * std::tuple_size<TupleT>()
// as we have T1, T2, T3
static const std::map<TypesEnumTuple, some_op_fn_t> m =
    make_my_map(std::make_index_sequence<27>());
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e0350a28366ec3c)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I will now try to figure out how to make this generic in `SomeOperation`/`some_op_fn_t`.

Comment: `std::size_t compile_time_pow(std::size_t a, std::size_t b)` might be better than `27`?  I'd also make `TupleT` a type template parameter and maybe an alias for `std::integral_constant<TypesEnum,?>`, but that is just cleanup.